# Why are swear words allowed in answers?

Tags: discussion, answers, offensive-flag

I saw these two answers: [Potentially offensive answer, open image at your own risk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zz2CM.png)

And I was wondering: Why are swear words still allowed in answers? It wouldn't be too hard to implement a word filter, and I don't see how these words could be appropriately used.

So I flagged one as NAA and the other one as R/A and downvoted both. Is that enough action?

Update: Looks like both are gone now.

Comment: I mean... i don't necessarily disagree with disallowing such obvious words that shouldn't ever be part of an answer, but at the same time... unless we already have a word blocklist, adding one when a solution to this problem already exists (RA flag) is only fixing half the problem. The RA post would still be RA without them.

Comment: Word filters are often counterproductive, since they can lead to the ["Scunthorpe problem"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem).

Comment: for the same reason we have the presumption of innocence as one of the guiding principles of justice and "assuming good faith" as a guiding principle of the Code of Conduct: the cost of blocking/banning/convicting innocuous posts/users/people (or, even worse, punishing) is higher than dealing with malicious intent retroactively. See 
Anderson Green's comment too.

Comment: A couple examples of issues this "simple" task is going to land in: [Brainfuck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck) programming language, "Do What The Fuck You Want To Public License" [license](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WTFPL) and others.

Comment: Oh, shoot: They were at least correct that my grammar needed to be fixed, even if they were _completely inappropriately_ in their response.

Comment: ["Cannot be done"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6099598/10248678)

Comment: Example of the Scunthorpe problem: *[The Clbuttic Mistake: When obscenity filters go wrong](https://web.archive.org/web/20200223093609/https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/newstopics/howaboutthat/2667634/The-Clbuttic-Mistake-When-obscenity-filters-go-wrong.html)*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no word filter, because word filters are easily avoided by people who intend to abuse the site (also making such posts harder to detect and review), and often counterproductive for legitimate users.

And there **are** potential legitimate reasons to use "bad words": Perhaps someone is having trouble with their profanity filter on Stack Overflow, or discussing the origins of an offensive slur over on English.SE.

It is, of course, a violation of site policy (not to mention common decency) to post the sort of profane, abusive answer that was in your screenshot.  Please flag any such posts as Rude/Abusive, as you did, so that they can be deleted as quickly as possible.

Answer (score 3):

They're not; custom flag for moderator attention and explain that *the post contains language that others would find offensive and is in violation of our Code of Conduct*.

<sup>Oh, I got some use out of that CoC document over on Stack Overflow after all.</sup>

As to your point about word filters - *implementing* one is simpler than *maintaining* it by several orders of magnitude.  See [the "Scunthorpe problem"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem).

Comment: That's because you strained too hard to do it. Just raise a Rude/Abusive flag. We don't need (or want) a custom flag for things that are obviously irredeemably rude/abusive.